# Django join tables to show data on the intersection between rows and columns

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-tables2

I've two class models, in which the first one (Activity) is prefilled by the admin, while the second (workingDays) is used as an input form to be filled by the website users, as follows:

```
class Activities(models.Model):
   activity= models.CharField(primary_key= True, max_length= 300)
   provider= models.CharField(max_length= 50)
   activity_id= models.CharField(max_length= 50)

class WorkingDays(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    activity= models.CharField(choices=labels, max_length=200)
    activity_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    worked_hours= models.FloatField(max_length=3)
    worked_days = models.FloatField(max_length=2)
```

I need to render a view to join the two models in one view and populate the data as illustrated below.

```
------------------------------------------
Activity  | user1 | user2 | user3 | user4|
------------------------------------------
act1      |   12  |       |   10  |      |
------------------------------------------
act2      |       |   20  |   10  |  10  |
------------------------------------------
act3      |   5   |       |   10  |  14  |
------------------------------------------
```

On the first column list all the available activity entries from the model(Activities) and on the rest of the columns each user of the model (WorkingDays). Then on the multiple rows populate the corresponding hours entered by each user for each activity

Any help using Django-ORM or django-tables?

Comment: you mean you want the user to open a page that tell him his worked_hours/days and some info?

Comment: I need to join the two models in one view and populate the data as illustrated on the first column list all the available activity entries from the model(Activities) and on the rest of the columns each user of the model (WorkingDays). Then on the multiple rows populate the corresponding hours entered by each user for each activity

Comment: You should create a Foreign key from WorkingDays model to Activities instead of storing activity and activity_id as char fields.

Comment: @sagar, that's a good idea but it will leads to a table with the following structure: user, activity, activity_id, worked_hours, worked_days as column tags. I need to put user on column tags, activity on rows tags, and worked_hours on the intersection cells